# How were Japanese elite divisions defeated?

Tags: world-war-two, japan, defense, allies

During the early months of the involvement of Japan in World War 2, Japanese land armies performed well against British, American and other Allied (Filipino, Dutch) troops. From my research, on books and internet, the usual explanation is that those troops were well-prepared, well-equipped, and had the experience of fighting in China.

However, it seems that later in the war, those divisions were not noticeable any more: most of the fights occurred on the water and in the air, and Japanese only seemed to perish.
Why is that? Why didn't the Japanese "elite" divisions did not oppose fierce resistance?
Which force of the Allies beat them (British, Chinese, Australian, American?), and where (Burma, China, Pacific?)?

My previous research already gave me this data on those "elite" divisions, where they fought after the victories of 1942, but it is sometimes incomplete:

**Malayan Campaign:**

- 18th division: One brigade destroyed at Guadalcanal. The rest destroyed in Burma
- 5th division: unclear: fought in New Guinea and Rabaul: this division was the true elite during the Malayan campaign, has it only faded in New Guinea?
- Imperial Guards: Did nothing, stayed in Japan?

**Burma 1942:**

- 33th division: destroyed à Imphal, reformed and destroyed in Burma
- 55th division: losses at Arakan battle (the second one), then in Burma

**Philippines:**

- 48th division: Did not fight? Only garrison in Java and Timor
- 16th division: Garrison in Manilla, then destroyed in the Philippines in 1944

**Armoured divisions:**

1st, 2nd and 3rd mainly fought in China, with some battalions destroyed in Guam and the Philippines, and some by the Soviets in Mandchuria at the end of the war

So why?
They were supposed to be the elite, and it seems like they just were slaughtered in Burma and the Philippines, even if those theater saw forces of equal size fighting (only 600 000 Americans facing 500 000 Japanese in the Philippines).

**EDIT:**

If it is not clear, I am interested in a detailed answer for each of these units about how they lost their potential: I understand the logistical issue overall, but then the question is:

- What are the numbers about supplies lost?
- How were those supplies lost (sea, air, land)?
- When were they lacking for those different units?
- Where those units actually beaten on the field, or just depleted by logistic lack?

The specific example of Kohima and Imphal battles was given in the comment: I know that the Japanese at Kohima lacked supplies, but they did not ask them to Japan territory: only to their superiors in Burma. So was the blocking point only in Burma?

EDIT:

I will focus on some specific examples: North Burma campaign by the Sino-American force.

Comment: They *weren't* very well-equipped, and their experience fighting Chinese soldiers who were even less well-equipped didn't prepare them very well for fighting more modern armies. There were other issues as well (e.g. a tactical doctrine which emphasized near-suicidal infantry charges) but logistics was definitely an Achilles heel for them.

Comment: The Burmese and New Guinea campaign were hampered by the lack of supplies. And, of course, the jungle does not care whether you're an elite soldier or not. ;)

Comment: I believe the premise of the question to be flawed. Assertions are being made with out evidence to back them up. For example some of the earlier battles was a lack of prepared troops on the allied side for how to deal with charging Japanese. Allied soldiers had never had hundreds of soldiers charge headlong into a barrage of bullets. Not to mention the Japanese were well dug in in the pacific theater at the start, but being well dug in and and well equipped are two different things.

Comment: Can I just have explanation on how the question lacks details or clarity?
There is one comment from @EvanM about assertions without evidence, is it related to the closing of the question?
I put details in the question about units I am interested in

Comment: @ThirstforKnowledge I understand the point about logistic for let's said New Guinea, but any evidence for Burma? I mean, I don't think US submarines were enough to cut an entire Japanese army, so much that it lost. About elite, I use this word precisely because the Japanese soldiers of the 5th or the 55th divisions were better than the Allies in jungle fighting

Comment: Logistic is not only about submarines and maritime traffic. You also need to bring supplies into the jungle with practically no roads. Japanese were pretty amateurish or "optimistic" considering logistic. Once they were stopped, they often suffered because they did create sufficient logistic chain to supply troops in the field.

Comment: The problem now, in my opinion, with your question is you're missing context. When we think of the progression of WWII You have to understand that a large portion of the fight was over supplies. Lack of men, lack of raw material, lack of skilled labor, lack of factories. When we talk about the Japanese late in the war, we are talking about a small island nation that had lost most of their fighters in charges and were low on supplies. The Ariska Model 99, I believe, is a great example. Early in the war it was a strong weapon. Late in the war it was nearly worthless. I'd switch to looking at

Comment: the state of the country late in the war for your answer. You're trying to find why regiments were loosing/non-effective on the battlefield by looking at the battlefield only when the answer is far more complex than that and we haven't even gotten to the inner political struggles and politics of the government later in the war.

Comment: @totalMongot They did have supply line from Bangkok to Rangoon (The Burma Railway) and up to Mandalay & Myitkyina. However, The [Japanese offensive in 1944](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_U-Go) was overly ambitious that they ended up short supplied their forces (the plan was to smash the Allied quickly and grab their supplies for further operations). As the plan failed and with no reliable supplies coming from Burma itself, starvation and disease took their toll.

Comment: @EvanM I would love to discuss of that with you... had the question not been closed. It is not because I am missing a point in history (here, logistics) that the question should be closed. By the way, had I not missed that point, I would not have asked this question..

Comment: Early in the war Japanese the were fighting second rate/inexperienced Western units.  The UK had its best troops fighting Germany, the US Army was pretty incompetent early on (see North Africa).  Given time, their early advantage in tactics and quality evaporated, they lost the initiative and they were fighting at times and places of their enemies' choosing, with insufficient supplies.  Tactics which were a plus early on, based on elan and morale, became a liability when Allied troops learned how to deal with them and kill at low cost to themselves.

Comment: When it is said that the Japanese units were well prepared, well prepared against who? The Chinese? The Chinese army was unequipped and unprepared in any imaginable ways. The French? The Dutch? The Britts? These guys were either already occupied by or very busy with the Germans. The Americans? Large part those soldiers had very little experience, and no good plans what happens in a case of invasion. The Soviets showed that being prepared helps. Also, how does front experience help an infantryman when is bombed from pains or battle ships?

Comment: well prepared for the attacks of 1942: Malaysia, Filippine, Burma....

Comment: Look in your question. Almost all those divisions you mention disappeared due to heavy attrition. You can't fight starvation.

Comment: Being _elite_ is a property that can be gained, due to extensive training and/or combat experience; but can also be lost, due to attrition or inactivity. So the question is not only about who is elite, it is also about when a unit is elite.

Comment: @Jos There was that much attrition in the Philippines? Units were lacking ammunition for example?